# how to add 2 attribute codes in if condition

Tags: php, attributes, if

i am using this code in attributes.phtml :

```
<?php 
if ($_data['code'] == 'mobile_design')
{ ?>
<td class="data">
<?php
$_ageValues = $_product->getAttributeText($_data['code']);
$count = 1;
?>
<?php if(is_array($_ageValues)): foreach($_ageValues as $_ageValue): ?>
<?php if($count > 1) { echo ","; } ?>
<?php echo $_ageValue; ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php endforeach; 
else: echo $_product->getAttributeText($_data['code']);
endif; ?>
</td>
```

in the 2nd line of the code you can see : `if ($_data['code'] == 'mobile_design')` , here "mobile_design" is a attribute, i want to add one more attribute here,  so i am using following code :

```
<?php 
    if (($_data['code'] == 'mobile_design') || ($_data['code'] == 'gendernew')) // please check this line
    { ?>
    <td class="data">
    <?php
    $_ageValues = $_product->getAttributeText($_data['code']);
    $count = 1;
    ?>
    <?php if(is_array($_ageValues)): foreach($_ageValues as $_ageValue): ?>
    <?php if($count > 1) { echo ","; } ?>
    <?php echo $_ageValue; ?>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; 
    else: echo $_product->getAttributeText($_data['code']);
    endif; ?>
    </td>
```

but its not working for me

Comment: i dont know why negative vote for this , please leave a comment, so i can correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course it doesn't work...

`($_data['code'] == 'mobile_design') && ($_data['code'] == 'gendernew')` will always evaluate to false.
If `$_data['code'] == 'mobile_design'` then it will never be `gendernew`.
Also if `$_data['code'] == 'gendernew'` then it will never be `mobile_design`.

so your expression evaluates to one of these cases:

```
true && false
false && true
false && false
```

all of the above evaluate to `false`. it's [logical conjunction 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction).

If you want your code to be executed for both `mobile_design` and `gendernew` cases replace `&&` with `||`.
`||` is [Logical Disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)

`true || false` evaluates to `true`
`false || true` evaluates to `true`
`false || false` evaluates to `false`

Comment: i updated the question and i am using following code : [  if (($_data['code'] == 'mobile_design') || ($_data['code'] == 'gendernew'))  ] , but it not working, please help me what else is wrong

Comment: maybe now it's not working because `$_data['code']` is neither `mobile_design` nor `gendernew`....just saying